# Почему не работает код? и выдает ошибку AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Tags: python, парсер, beautiful-soup

```py
import requests
from bs4 import  BeautifulSoup as BS
url = 'https://finance.rambler.ru/calculators/converter/1-USD-RUB/'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BS(r.content, 'html.parser')
man = soup.find('div', class_='plcu converter-display__currency').text
print(man)
```

*Не могу понять почему выдает такую ошибку*

PS. Этот код заходит на сайт url и парсит оттуда информацию

Comment: Дело в том, что `soup.find(...)` (в предпоследней строке) вернул `None`.

Comment: @Vladimir Chistov  то есть `.text  не нужен? если да то как сделать так чтоб код работал? Заранее благодарю

Comment: видимо функция `soup.find` в случае неудачи возвращает `None`. Нужно проверять её результат на `None`.

Comment: @robot228, а откуда там класс `plcu`? Смотрел по ссылке и не увидел. Если его уберет, то найдется `USD`

Comment: @gil9red это я посмотрел в коде сайта

Comment: @robot228, https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7Ogp.png А у вас как?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В структуре сайта отсутствует класс plcu:

```
url = 'https://finance.rambler.ru/calculators/converter/1-USD-RUB/'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BS(r.content, 'html.parser')
man = soup.find_all('div', class_='converter-display__currency-body')
for i in man:
    print(i.text)
```

Comment: У этого кода output: USD
RUB
USD
RUB
RUB
USD

Comment: Вопрос был про ошибку, у вас была ошибка в названии класса, "plcu" был не нужен. Я поправил код, изменил название класса на "class_='converter-display__currency-body'", теперь он возвращает значения. Вы можете использовать просто "print(i)", что бы посмотреть содержимое ответа и вытащить именно те данные, которые нужны Вам.

Comment: Cпасибо большое, я разобрался с этим благодарю